# Необходимо из последовательности убрать минимальное кол-во букв, чтобы подпоследовательность исчезла

Tags: строки

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы помочь с решением задачи (хотя-бы алгоритмом).
Дана подпоследовательность и последовательность букв. Необходимо из последовательности убрать минимальное кол-во букв, чтобы подпоследовательность исчезла. Например babcaсbc и подпоследовательность abc. Необходимо из последовательности либо обе а, либо вторую и третью b. Пока что все придуманные способы слишком длительны по выполнению.
Максимальная длинна последовательности 10000, а подпоследовательности 1000. В последовательности babcacbc, подпоследовательности не только первая и вторая abc, но и первая "a" и последние "cb"

Comment: `Необходимо из последовательности либо обе а, либо вторую и третью b` - почему не только одну "а" или только вторую "б"? Ведь в предоставленной строке именно этого и достаточно. Или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: a "с" удалить только первую и вторую?

Comment: Покажите хоть 1 придуманный способ. А то мне не удалось придумать рабочий "слишком длительный" способ выполнения для такой задачи

Comment: Внес правки, проблема в том, что строка может состоять из 10000 латинских букв в верхнем и нижнем регистре (рассматриваются как разные), и подстрока из 1000. Также подстрокa "abc" будет присутствовать в строке например "azzzzbuuuc".

Comment: @DenisMischenko abc в azzzzbuuuc - не подстрока, либо у вас какое-то своё определение подстроки

Comment: Я вам говорю, как дано условие. Быть может подстрока не верное название. Задание подразумевает, что abc в azzzzbuuuc - подпоследовательность.

Comment: в azzzzbuuuc не существует подстроки abc. Определяйтесь с терминологией. Я так понимаю, вам нужен нечёткий поиск, т.е. не важно сколько между a и b будет символов, важна последовательность. В этом случае копайте, например, алгоритмы по следующей ссылке: https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/

Answer (score 0):

1. Строка в которой делаем поиск = строка, которую ищем = паттерн (чтобы не путаться)
2. Определяем длину паттерна, целочисленно делим его на 2, прибавляем 1. Получаем номер буквы, оптимальной к удалению.
3. организуем цикл, в котором будет производиться поиск паттерна, в случае успеха - удаление в строке буквы по найденному адресу + тот самый номер из пункта 1, затем поиск производится повторно, но уже начиная с найденного адреса. Поиск проводится до тех пор, пока не будет отрицательным.
   Мне проще написать это, например, на паскале:

> ```
> var
>   str, substr:string;  
>   k,l1,l2:integer;  
> begin  
>   l1:=length(substr) div 2 + 1;  
>   l2:=length(str);  
>   k:=1;  
>   repeat  
>     k:=PosEx(substr, str, k);  
>     if k>0 then  
>        str:=Copy(str,1,k+l1-2) + Copy(str,k+l1,l2-k-l1+1);  
>   until k = 0;  
> end;
> ```

Comment: Я видно не совсем понятно написал условие, я внес коррективы в задание и написал еще пример в комментарии к нему, также есть ограничение по времени 2 секунды, память не ограниченна.

Comment: Без разницы, алгоритм всё равно будет работать.

Comment: к сожалению он не работает для примера который я написал, ввод: "babcacbc" "abc" вывод: bacacbc подпоследовательность abc остается на буквах номер 2, 6 и 7 или 4, 6 и 7.

Comment: Но, разумеется, имея в виду строку и подстроку ТАК, как понимают её программисты. Про ваше понимание я ответил в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: я с самого начала написал последовательность и подпоследовательность, а не строка и подстрока.